# Change IE default File Browsing Folder

Tags: c#, windows

When you need to upload a file using IE, a file browsing dialog will open and let you choose a file.
In future whenever you try to upload a file, previously selected file's location will be displayed as first folder in file browsing dialog.
After some researches I find out opened file's information will save in this location of registry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ComDlg32\OpenSavePidlMRU
```

I need to Change IE default File Browsing Folder from code.

Comment: Can't you just change the registry value?

Comment: No, it is very Complex.